# Adminimize Plugin -- Is there an alternative to limiting Editor to 'Appearance > Widgets' only?

Tags: plugins, php, functions

Adminimize > Menu Options: I want to grant access to "Appearance > Widgets" *only* to select users (but not Themes, Editor, Add New Themes; nor Plugins, Settings). Although I have selected this in the Adminimize menu, "Appearance > Widgets" does not show on users' dashboard. Is there a solution?

APPEARANCE (themes.php)

-- Themes (themes.php)

-- Widgets (widgets.php)

-- Editor (theme-editor.php)

-- Add New Themes (theme-install.php)

Comment: This appears to be a basic, Plugin-specific support question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that APPEARANCE (themes.php) is set to display on the users dashboard, and then make sure that Themes, Editor and Add New Themes are set to hide.

If the parent is set to hide, then even if a child is set to display it will still be hidden.